# local video file cannot get accessed from firefox extension

Tags: video, firefox-addon, html5-video

I'm running a very strange problem while trying to develop a firefox extension. As part of an experiment, I'm trying to make a custom overlay on firefox's **SSL Error Page**. What I'm trying to do is to play a video using HTLM5's video tag. The video runs well if I put a remote video (e.g youtube video) as video source. But problem occurs whenever I try to access my local  video files. I've tried with this several file paths :

1. file:///Users/Me/Desktop/sample.mp4 --> shows error **No video with supported format & MIME type found**
2. relative path ../video/sample.mp4 --> shows error **Invalid file URI**
3. "chrome://sslerrorpage/content/images/Take04.webm" --> shows error as the first one

My code is as follows :

```
       <video autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" width="500" height="400" poster="sample.gif">
<source src="file:///C:/Users/BraseLab/Desktop/sample.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.thewikies.com%2Fvfe-generator%2Fimages%2Fbig-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',{'url':'chrome://sslerrorpage/content/images/Take04.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
            <img alt="Big Buck Bunny" src="chrome://sslerrorpage/content/images/Take04.gif" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
```

Interestingly, any image file shows up with local file path, but not the video files!!! I'm newbie in firefox extension development, so I request you guys to suggest me what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this on a chrome page? Or a random website?

Comment: No, this is on a SSL warning page where the browser shows **Your connection is not secured**

Answer (score 1):

If this is an add-on, then you should setup a [`resource:` uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#resource) or [`chrome:` uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#category) and use that for all of your content.